# Gigabit connection and router, but I only get 100 Mbps on my PC

Tags: networking, router, gigabit-ethernet

I got a gigabit connection from my ISP (with PPPoE connection). Tested with the cable directly in the PC, works great, I get 1000 Mbps.

I bought an [ASUS AC55U router](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTAC55U/), which claims to have gigabit ports, but if I put the cable in the router and connect the pc to the router, I only get 100 Mbps speeds. The connection status claims the speed is 1.0 Gbps:

[image: Ethernet status]

I have a CAT 5E 4 pair cable, and as I mentioned before  it works fine if I plug it in directly in the PC. All the drivers are installed, router has latest firmware.

I have no idea where else to look. I don't have any other gigabit routers to try.

Edit: visual representation:

with router https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gBII.png

without router https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNXyM.png

Comment: do all the RJ-45 connections at least show a green light, not yellow ?

Comment: Have you tried testing the speed over the router between two PCs?

Comment: Tetsujin: do you mean at the ethernet port in the PC? It's one green light and one orange.

CShark: no, I don't have any other PCs

Comment: How have you connected the router to the internet connection?  Via WAN or LAN port?  If wan, try connecting using LAN, and initate the pppoe connection from your PC as you did in the same way you did with a direct connection.

Comment: Paul: what sorcery is this? I tried it and it did connect, but I still get only 100 Mbps speeds

Comment: The router's internet connection settings have probably not been set to run at 1000Mbps or some of its ports are not. You probably have to check the router's own port settings to find out. Better check from the manual, or inquire from the product forums. If you have  gigabit Ethernet switch connect through it instead to check.

Comment: Broadly speaking, green light means the physical hardware connection negotiated at 1000Base-T, orange/yellow means it only reached 100Base-T - so check your cabling.

Comment: vfclists: there are no settings for changing the speed of the lan ports.

Tesujin: the same coloring is present when I plug the cable directly into the computer and it gives a gigabit connection

Comment: Have you manually set the speed on your NIC to 1GB or is it set to "auto"?

Comment: I have also set it manually to 1.0 Gbps full duplex, and I get the same bad result. I will return this router and get a new one today, and I will post back the result.

Comment: I've replaced the router with and Archer C7 and again I can't get Gigabit speeds through the router. I think I'm going to go insane!

Answer (score 2):

1. Maybe your ethernet cable doesn't support a 1Gbit/s connection (physical problem).
2. Maybe you have to activate Gbit-LAN in your router settings. You can get there by typing in ipconfig (on windows) and type in your gateway address into your browser.

Good Luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The cable does support gigabit connection. If I plug in directly into the computer, it works fine. I have also checked the settings on my router, and there is no option for setting gigabit (it should be enabled by default). The computer also sees the connection to the router as gigabit (see screenshot)

Comment: Hey Nini. Only because the computer sees the 1Gbit connection, doesn't mean that it really is one. The router could also just send, that it is trying to send 1Gbit, but is failing. Has to be a physical problem between router and computer or directly on your computer Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe most onboard lan are rated at 100 Mbps.(I have a pc 10 yrs old) I bought a wireless 5G usb connector and  a 3.0 usb pci card. With the two and make sure you are connected to the 5G wifi port, 1  get up to 250 mbps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).